# Format String to JSON for jqGrid use

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have the below `txt` from csv. I want to convert it to Json format.

```
id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00"
id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00"

var js = '';

var rows = txt.split('\n');
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    js += '{' + rows[i] + '},';
}

js = js.slice(0, -1); //remove the last comma

var obj = JSON.parse('{' + js + '}'); //Error Expected '}' on Line1 Column 2
```

How to properly format text to json or array that will be accepted by jqgrid?

```
colModel: [
                    {label: 'Inv No', name: 'id', width: 75, key: true},
                    {label: 'Date', name: 'invdate', width: 90},
                    {label: 'Client', name: 'name', width: 100},
                    {label: 'Amount', name: 'note', width: 80},
                    {label: 'Tax', name: 'amount', width: 80},
                    {label: 'Total', name: 'tax', width: 80},
                    {label: 'Notes', name: 'total', width: 150}
                ],
```

Comment: It's very strange question. Why you have so strange formatted input data? In any way you need quote the names of properties (for example convert the text `name: "test"` to `"name": "test"`) to make correct input data for `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I have no control on the given txt, its from csv, anyway to answer my own question :), I resulted on using array.

`var o = [];
            d = {};
            var rows = txt.split('\n');
            
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var r = rows[i];
                d = eval('({' + r + '})');
                o.push(d);
            }`